# Sco Unix Grep Specific Number (ID)

Tags: java, unix, grep, sco-unix

I have a programme I am writing for work.

it connects onto our Sco Unix server and runs a command, which most of the time works fine

```
String command = "ps -eo ruser,pid,ppid,stime,etime,tty,args | sort -k4 | grep /PGProcid="+ProcID+"\\ | grep -v grep";
```

Which when output can look like the following for example

```
ps -eo ruser,pid,ppid,stime,etime,tty,args | sort -k4 | grep /PGProcid=1\ | grep -v grep
```

However if I try and do this for a single number (normally 1 but not restricted to it) I get no results, even though I know the results exist.

for example if I have the following results on the server

```
# ps -ef | grep /PGProcid=1
 name 29175 29174  0 02:55:57  ttyp15    00:00:00 /xxx/xxx/xxx/prog6 /PGProcid=14
 person2 28201 28199  0 01:15:27  ttyp13    00:00:00 /xxx/xxx/xxx/prog1 /PGProcid=1
```

Then if I do the following

```
# ps -ef | grep /PGProcid=1\
```

I get no results but I know there is results for 1, the above will work if i use double digits like 14 will bring back the results.

I basically need to be able to grep for the /PGProcid= to get the PID and PPID numbers. This only seems to not work where there's 1 & 10,11,12 etc or 2 & 20,21,22 so on.

I have tried Egrep, and using $'s but it always seem to skip the single digit numbers!

EDIT:
Here's what i have tried on this server

```
  # echo $SHELL
  /bin/sh
  ps -ef | grep PGProcid=2
  amanda 23602 25207  0 09:22:58       ?    00:00:06 /xxxxxx /PGProcid=2
  amanda 25207 25203  0   Feb-28       ?    00:00:01 /xxxxxx /PGProcid=2
  root 26389 26034  0 05:15:22   ttyp6    00:00:00 grep PGProcid=2
  amanda 26042 23602  0 04:46:16       ?    00:00:04 /xxxxxx /PGProcid=2
```

so 2 is active currently on their server however the below give no results

```
  # ps -ef | grep /PGProcid=2$
  # ps -ef | grep /PGProcid=2\$
  # ps -ef | grep "/PGProcid=2$"
```

The below gives results but also picks up anything with a 2 in it so 22 etc where im only after 2

```
   # ps -ef | grep '/PGProcid=2$'
```

Below gives an error "No such file or directory"

```
   # ps -ef | grep `/PGProcid=2$`
```

Comment: `grep "/PGProcid=1$"`  works fine to me.

Comment: Alternatively, try escaping the `$` with `grep /PGProcid=1\$` as `$` will probably be expanded by your shell.

Comment: Also, people would point out that it would be better answered on [Unix Stackexchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @fedorqui didn't you forget the trailing `"` (which would protect the `$`)?

Comment: That's done it, adding the $ to the end of the \ has solved it, been bashing my head against a wall for the last hour googling it thanks!

Comment: Yes, @Matthieu, thanks I updated

Comment: @Matthieu Didn't know it existed, but now I do thanks

Comment: @ChristopherLewis you're welcome. Stackexchange has almost one site per type of question anybody could ever ask about anything :)

Comment: Backquotes will execute the command in between and replace it with the output of the command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your shell will try to expand `$` with an environment variable. You have to protect it `$` with either a `\`:

```
grep /PGProcid=1\$
```

or `""`:

```
grep "/PGProcid=1$"
```

Edit:
To be more precise, you should use the `\>` to match the empty string at the end of a **word**. And as both `\` and `>` are interpreted by the shell, you should protect them as well:

```
grep /PGProcid=1\\\>
```

or

```
grep "/PGProcid=1\>"
```

If you want to have a "word match" (which it seems to me), you can also try the `-w` option:

```
grep -w /PGProcid=1
```

Comment: That hasn't gone as well as planned. That seemed to work on that server, however another server is now giving me no results same grep line single digit that does exist but the line doesn't pick it up

Comment: @ChristopherLewis is the other server using the same shell (i.e both using bash, ksh, ...)? You might want to try single quotes `'` instead of double `"` as single quotes won't expand anything.

Comment: They appear to be running different shells, one is using /usr/bin/bash the other is using /bin/sh I guess my options are editing the profiles on the servers so all shells match, or trying to find some common ground?

Comment: @ChristopherLewis using the same shell would be easier for you as you could use the same scripts everywhere. However, if not possible, try using simple quotes `'`.

Comment: Sorry removed that reply from my comment I did try single quotes but it didn't like those either found no results, if I can find a way of getting it to work on the /usr/bin/bash I could add in a check to see what shell that server ran and execute a different command

Comment: I managed to change the shell to SH, however it still doesnt find the ID in the original format so now im more confused !

Comment: @ChristopherLewis it should work with bash (my tests were done with bash). Check the `man sh` and `man bash` for differences about character protection.

Comment: I tried all options, ive updated my original post to show what ive tried, looking at the escape items \ should be enough however it doesnt seem to roll that way

Comment: @ChristopherLewis edited my answer for you to try the `\>` match or `-w` option of grep. It looks fine on my bash. Tell me if it works. If it does not, try asking the question on Unix Stackexchange.

Comment: Hi Matthieu thanks again for the help. -w doesn't work on my shell, illegal option. I do use -w on the Mac servers we have. The sco ones don't like this. the "/PGProcid=1\>" also brings back no results. However i did modify the grep /PGProcid=1\\\> and removed the > from the end giving me grep /PGProcid=1\\\ this seems to be working at present, but im guessing if I find another server that doesn't like it im back to square one! Thanks for the help anyway and ill try the command and see if anything causes any more issues and if it does ill try putting it up on the unix one! Thanks again